# PHP GCM appengine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use gcm in appengine using PHP runtime. Following is the code, which uses URLFetch service

```
$context = array("https"=>
             array( "method" => "post",
                "content" => json_encode($fields),
                "header" => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                            "Authorization: key=" . GOOGLE_API_KEY . "\r\n"
            )
        );
    $context = stream_context_create($context);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Following is the Original code that uses PHP Curl:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

PHP code that uses Curl works well, but the code that uses urlfetch service of appengine does't work. Can someone tell me where am I doing wrong.

Comment: what error do you see back?

Comment: i dont see any error. But the "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" is being redirected to "http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html" and no GCM message is being sent

Comment: Please take a look in my solution. It's working:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998875/googlecloudmessaging-returning-invalidregistration

Comment: page not found for the link you provided :(

Comment: I think this is the link he tried to type: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969191/googlecloudmessaging-php-script-always-returning-invalidregistration) I went there, there was no clue too. I have the same problem, looking for the answer.

Comment: Maybe this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567824/gae-php-and-gcm-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-0-405-metho

Answer (score 2):

This is tested code.

```
    public function sendAndroidPushNotification($registration_ids, $message)
    {
         // Adding devicetoken in array
         $registrationIds = array($registration_ids);
         $msg = array(
            'message' => $message,
            'title' => 'notification center',
            'tickerText' => $message,
            'vibrate' => 1,
            'sound' => 1,
        );

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
            'data' => $msg
        );
        $fields = json_encode($fields);
        $arrContextOptions=array(
            "http" => array(
                "method" => "POST",
                "header" =>
                    'Authorization: key = '. "\r\n" .
                    'Content-Type: application/json'. "\r\n",
                "content" => $fields,
            ),
            "ssl"=>array(
                "allow_self_signed"=>true,
                "verify_peer"=>false,
            ),
        );
        $arrContextOptions = stream_context_create($arrContextOptions);
        $result = file_get_contents('https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send', false, $arrContextOptions);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, Thank you! Could you better format the code?