# Getting Invalid registration error for GCM using PHP

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create push notification for android using php. But I stuck somewhere.I am using an example from for that. Here is my php code

Web config

```
<?php
/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "");

/*
 * Google API Key
 */
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AIzaSyD_PC6UaeTbnSemX0hpY0eyawlE3EufRcA"); // Place your Google API Key
?>
```

And my GCM.php File is this

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of GCM
 *
 * @author Ravi Tamada
 */
class GCM {

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }

}

?>
```

My html is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="" method="post" action="register.php">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="text" name="email"/>
            <input type="text" name="regId"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This the code which I am using but everytime it show me message that 
{"multicast_id":4677806556758130005,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

I donot know what I am doing wrong

I am getting confuse with GCM Registration Id which I have to pass. Can anybody tell me what is this and where I find it

I tried my project id and project number for that But I got this error again and again

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: your API key is invalid thats why it gives you error

Comment: But I copy it from my google console and paste it as it is .

Comment: pls genrate new one. and check with it.

Comment: You can try the solution offered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969191/googlecloudmessaging-php-script-always-returning-invalidregistration

Answer (score 0):

Please pass **server key** of your gcm account if not generated please generate it and pass it it will works 100%

Comment: can u please tell me what is reg id ? I am not getting what is that

Comment: registration id is a unique id of your device where you will send push notification and server key will set in GOOGLE_API_KEY

Comment: this issue is because of your server key please check anything wrong in your google account or you define different server key in GOOGLE_API_KEY