# Error in sending request Google Cloud Messaging in PHP

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Google Clouding Messaging API to integrate with Android App. For backend, I am using Laravel 5.2. I generated 3 api keys in Google API. These are server API key, Android API key and browser API key. I am referencing on this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

This is my push request from server to GCM server:

```
private function sendNotification($registatoin_ids,$message)
{
  $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

  $fields = array(
      'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
      'data' => $message,
  );

  $headers = array(
      'Authorization: key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
      'Content-Type: application/json'
  );

  // Open connection
  $ch = curl_init();

  // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

  // Execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if ($result === FALSE)
  {
      die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
  }

  // Close connection
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $result;
}

function register(Request $request)
{
  $name            = $request->name;
  $email           = $request->email;
  $gcm_regid       = $request->reg_ids;
  $registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regid);
  $message         = array("product" => "shirt");
  $result          = $this->sendNotification($registatoin_ids,$message);
  echo $result;
}
```

I called register function. `email`, `name` and `reg_ids` are mock values. I just passed `myemail`, `myname` and random string respectively. Register function is the action of the controller. For `GOOGLE_API_KEY`, I passed server api key. But when I request, it is giving me following error.

`{"multicast_id":5065519232839143946,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}`

Is my push request correct? Can I pass any unique value to `reg_ids`. Moreover, is my `GOOGLE_API_KEY` should be Android, server or browser key?

Answer (score 0):

The error you receive is [401 HTTP status code](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes), which means that the sender account used to send a message couldn't be authenticated. Here are the possible causes:

- Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax in HTTP request.
- Invalid project number sent as key.
- Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
- Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs.
- The API key is not valid.

Check that the token you're sending inside the Authentication header is the correct API key associated with your project. See [Checking the validity of an API Key](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#checkAPIkey) for details.

Also try to check this related SO question [17969191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969191/googlecloudmessaging-php-script-always-returning-invalidregistration) and [11242743](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging?rq=1) for more information.